# What changes IDT after initialization on Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64 and change the kernel to official version 2.6.32.61 on Intel core i7 3632.

I put some code into Linux kernel just before rest_init(in start_kernel of init/main.c) to record all 256 descriptors in the IDT. And then I found that the gate descriptors from 20 to 31 were modified when I checked them again after the system was fully initialized.

As far as I know there's no more modifications on IDT after init_IRQ which happens before my recording in the initilization procedure. And according to Intel developer manual exception 20 is used for virtualization and exception 21 to 31 is reserved(should not be used).

My question is:
What changes gate descriptors from 20 to 31 in IDT after initialization?